# How to get the individual parameter using $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] in php

Tags: php

I need some help. I need to get each individual values from query string using php  `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`. I am explaining my code below.

```
http://localhost/php/get.php?name=A + B&cid=20
```

This is the URL. Here I need to fetch each exact  value differently.means the result should come `name=A + B` and `cid=20`. Here I am using `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`. I am explaining my code below.

```
<?php
$query=$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
echo $query;
?>
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: `echo $_GET['name'];`

Comment: `echo $_GET['cid'];`

Comment: 10 Answers with same stuff coming in shortly!

Comment: I have tried with `$_GET` method but the output is coming for name is `A B` and there is no `+` sign.

Comment: The + sign just means space, an actual plus sign needs to be url encoded as `%2B`

Comment: @Augwa : I need to get the full value `A + B`.

Comment: URL is not encoded.

Comment: I have given the url.

Comment: `A + B` just means `A   B` but `A %2B B` means `A + B`

Comment: @Augwa: I have given `name=A + B`  and i need to get the exact value.

Comment: @subhra you aren't listening at all. + is treated as a space character in a URL. Read all my comments.

Comment: @Augwa : Ok,Can you please write the exact solution.

Comment: I have no idea how you're sending that request. Read up on Url Encoding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139818/discussion-between-subhra-and-augwa).

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and you can get the individual value of the variables:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_GET);
echo "</pre>";

echo $_GET['name'];
echo $_GET['cid'];
```

Comment: No,its not coming as per expected.Please read my all comments from above.

Comment: Use urldecode() function to decode "name" value;
    echo urlencode($_GET['name']));
    urlencode() send the same value which you expect.

Comment: Yes,you are right.BUt if space is there then one extra `+` is adding inside that string.

Comment: Use "rawurlencode()" which helps to encode your variable and use "rawurldecode()" function to decode your variable
    this echo rawurldecode($_GET['name']);

Comment: i did like this `echo rawurldecode($_GET['name']);` and this `A  B` came.

Comment: Can you write the full code please ?

Comment: Use This
    <?php
    echo $url = "http://localhost/excel/test.php?name=".rawurlencode("A + B");
    echo '<a href="'.$url.'">Test</a>';

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_GET);
    echo "</pre>";

    echo rawurldecode($_GET['name']);
    ?>

Comment: Is this code working for you??